# why am I having trouble assigning properties with varying types?

Tags: typescript

I am trying to set a class instance member property to the value of a typed object that accepts dynamic values.  The class instance member property is boolean, and the value I have set on the object is a boolean...

```
interface Cat {
  [ index: string ] : string | number | boolean
}

class Test {
  private result : boolean | undefined;

  doIt () {
    let c: Cat = { purring: true }
    this.result = cat.purring;
  }
}
```

I get an error on the line that is trying to assign `this.result`:

> Type 'string | number | boolean' is not assignable to type 'boolean |
> undefined'.   Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'boolean |
> undefined'.

I seem to only be able to make this work if I do:

```
this.result = cat.purring as boolean;
```

Which I am hoping I don't have to do... ?
...

And then a similar problem, I am simply trying to allow a value of an array of strings or an array of arrays of strings:

```
type StringOrNestedString = string[] | StringOrNestedString[]

interface Item {
  filters: StringOrNestedString,
}

let i: Item = {
  filters: ['foo', ['bar']],
}
```

and I get:

> Type '(string | string[])[]' is not assignable to type 'StringOrNestedString'.
> Type '(string | string[])[]' is not assignable to type 'string[]'.

Answer (score 0):

The error is legit; That `cat` can be an object whose attributes can be either `string | number | boolean`, but `Test#result` can be `boolean | undefined`. Picture a venn diagram, and you realise that only a subset of `Cat` can be assigned to `Test#result`: only when it's a boolean.

What typescript is warning you is:

```
    let cat: Cat = { purring: true }
    // this is allowed
    cat.purring = 123
    // which means that this should error out
    this.result = cat.purring;
```

So, narrow it down to handle that scenario:

```
    if (typeof cat.purring !== 'boolean') {
      // throw or somethihng
      return
    }

    this.result = cat.purring;
```

About the recursive type:

```
type StringOrNestedString = string | Array<StringOrNestedString | string>
```

Comment: ultimately this is coming from an api, which will always be boolean...  having to safe guard against types in this case just seems so silly to me...  So I guess casting as boolean is my best bet?

Comment: I'd really try to avoid casting if it is possible, rather try to correct/amend/patch the types to reflect what you expect it to be. It could very well be a very simple `const cat = toCat(myVeryBroadApiResponse) // this doesn't need to do much rather than return a type that make sense for the consumer, narrowing it down, and it serve as an anti corruption layer of sort`. As soon as you litter your code with a bunch of `as`, you are going to fight the type system, and you will not get most of the benefits

Comment: sigh.. ok.. I am just really struggling with typescript (converting an angularJS to angular), and it's...  not proving to be easy.  Another problem I just came up with regarding the string arrays is, that property can also be a function... So really what I want is:  `interface XYZ { filters: Array<string | string[]> | (arg0: any) => void }`. but despite having code that does `if (typeof x.filters === 'function') { x.filters(someArg) }` I get: ` Not all constituents of type '(string | string[])[] | ((arg0: any) => void)' are callable.` Why is that happening if I am explicitly checking the type?